# NVD3 - redraw/refresh chart when data isn't changing

Tags: angularjs, nvd3.js

I pull the data from my **Chart** service. The data pulled has 2 properties I want switch between on the y axis (**someData** and **someOtherData**). The idea is that based on a click event in my parent controller, the chart will display a different property on my y axis (either **someData** or **someOtherData**):

```
y: function(d){ return $scope.mode === '1' ? d.someData : d.someOtherData; }
```

This is my directive's controller. The code below will only do what I want if I re-fetch the data every time I want to switch between properties:

```
 controller: function($scope, Chart) {
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.data = Chart.testPortfolio(); // I only want data to be fetched once as it doesn't changes

        $scope.update = function() {
            //$scope.data = Chart.testPortfolio();  <-- if this line is uncommented it works, but I don't want to fetch data on every click event
            $scope.pieOptions = {
                chart: {
                    type: 'pieChart',
                    height: 400,
                    x: function(d){ return d.name; },
                    y: function(d){ return $scope.mode === '1' ? d.someData : d.someOtherData; },
                    showLabels: false,
                    labelThreshold: 0.01
                }
            };
        }
        $scope.update();

        // this listens to my click event for switching
        $scope.$on('some-event', function(e, args) {
            $scope.mode = args.mode;
            $scope.update();
        });
    }
```

And this is the html of the directive:

```
<nvd3 options='pieOptions' data='data'></nvd3>
```

How can I redraw/update the chart, without having to re-fetch the data every time I want to switch properties for y axis?

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution, which it's more like a **hack**. So if you have better suggestions please let me know:

```
        controller: function($scope, Chart, $interval) {
        $scope.data = [];
        $scope.pieOpts = {
            chart: {
                type: 'pieChart',
                height: 400,
                x: function(d){ return d.name; },
                y: function(d){ return $scope.mode === '1' ? d.someValue: d.someOtherValue; },
                showLabels: false,
                labelThreshold: 0.01
            }
        };

        $scope.data = Chart.testPortfolio();

        $scope.$on('some-event', function(e, args) {
            if(args.mode !== $scope.mode) {
                $scope.mode = args.mode;

                var tempData = angular.copy($scope.data.reverse());

                $interval(function () {
                    $scope.data = [];
                    while((a=tempData.pop()) != null){
                        $scope.data.push(a);
                    }
                }, 1, true);
            }
        });
    }
```